# Adding a new Cassandra node without downtime

Tags: cassandra

Currently testing Cassandra with a single node and am planning to learn how to add a new node tomorrow.  My question beforehand is, will adding a new node cause downtime for any apps which connect to the current single node for data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, there is not going to be any downtime, but depending on the load from the application, you may have some impact on the performance while the streaming occurs; another factor to take in consideration is the specification of the server where the node is running.

What is the motivation behind scaling up the cluster, is it to free space or improve the performance? if that is the case the cleanup on the old node, once that the scale-up will be very important to reclaim space. If you are scaling up to increase the resilience of the cluster (the ability to lose a node without impacting the service) you'll need to increase the replication factor (with an

> alter keyspace

statement); in both cases, you will also need to be sure to execute a repair on the cluster.

Are these bare metal or cloud instances? with bare metal servers is particularly important that the topology is consistent with your setup.